# Cannot select certain webcams at application level. How to?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, webcam

Ubuntu 20.04 & 22.04.

Logitech Web Cam (External USB)

The web cam is detected and works in webcamoid but not in cheese on an Arm64 22.04 system.

The same webcam is detected by the OS on an Intel 20.04 system (which also has another built it webcam which is also working) using lssub & "v4l2-ctl --list devices" but is not detected at the application level by cheese or webcamoid.

The device /dev/video2 is there and has the correct group and permissions.

Not sure why the applications are not allowing me to select that camera!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the Intel 20.04 Ubuntu system to 22.04 it worked the same as the ARM64 Ubuntu 22.04 systems.

All systems can now see the Logitec webcam from webcamoid but not Cheese.